# Where do I find the Connector/C++ debug package (X DevAPI)?

Tags: c++, mysql, mysql-x-devapi

I was able to build a MyySQL\C++ project in release mode, but I'd like to build it in debug mode as well. The documentation says that I'll need to install the Connector/C++ debug package in order to build in debug mode, but the debug package is no where to be found. The binary installation doesn't have the debug package, so where can I find it?

Here is the link to the documentation explaining how to install MySQL/C++:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/8.0/en/connector-cpp-installation-binary.html

Here is the link to the documentation explaining how to build for Windows
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/8.0/en/connector-cpp-apps-windows-notes.html

Windows 10
Visual Studio 2019 Community

Comment: Bottom of the page ? https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/cpp/

Comment: Oh wow thanks! Sorry for the noob question